# segfault when calling two function in one expression of the range-for loop C++

Tags: c++, function, for-loop, segmentation-fault, set

I have big program, it does exactly like the mini version of the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

map<int,set<size_t>> getMap(void) {
    return map<int,set<size_t>>{
        {1,{2,3,4,5}},
        {2,{3,4,5,6}}
    };
}

int getIndex(void) {
    return 1;
}

int main(void) {
    for (const size_t &n: getMap()[getIndex()])
        cout << n << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

the result I got is a segmentation fault. I made mistake here, but don't know exactly where the mistake is. `getMap()[getIndex()])` is the experssion that I considered to be the error. But I believed the expression should be return a container `set<size_t>`, which I can iterate through.

Can someone explain why calling those function in one expression produce segmentation fault on the above code ? Did I try to access something that shouldn't be accessed?  Or I missed how the compiler behave when processing such an expression?

Comment: Do not tag `C` for C++ code.

Comment: `getMap()[getIndex()]` is a dangling reference in `for` range loops unfortunately. Save it into a local variable.

Comment: `getMap()[getIndex()]` -- This returns a temporary that gets destroyed immediately.

Comment: Note that this is recognized as a defect in C++, and a fix has been proposed: https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2644r1.pdf I'm not clear on whether this change made it into C++23.

Comment: Lifetime extension of a temporary in the loop's *range-expression* was actually addressed in C++23 (see [P2718R0](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2718r0.html)), but it doesn't appear any compiler implements the fix yet (see [Compiler support for C++23](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/23)).

Answer (score 3):

Your `getMap` function returns an instance of a map, but in a ranged-based `for` loop, the entity on the right side of the `:` must persist throughout the running of the loop.

In your case, the `getMap()` returned map will no longer exist on the second iteration.

The fix is to assign the return value of `getMap()` to a variable that will remain in-scope within the ranged-based `for`:

```
int main(void) {
    auto m = getMap()[getIndex()]; // assign to a variable that will not be destroyed.
    for (const size_t &n : m)
        cout << n << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/3Ys6qKsd1)

Comment: Another potential fix is to not return a different object every time `getMap()` is called.

Comment: Note: in C++20 and later, you can move `m` into the *init-statement* of the loop so it stays within the scope of just the loop and not the surrounding code, eg: `for(auto m = getMap()[getIndex()]; const size_t &n : m) { ... }`